# outlined text not recognized by tesseract

Tags: text, ocr, tesseract, outline

I scoured the internet but could not find an answer to this really simple question.

When I use Canny edge detection on my image the text shows up as outlined by the edges.  For some reason, Tesseract OCR does not recognize the text then.  It does recognize the text when it is not outlined like that and just normal text.

What do I have to do to get tesseract to recognize the outlined text?  I tried thinning the image first implementing a thinning algorithm from scratch but that just seemed to make the Canny edge detection worse.

Comment: I assume you got non-text content on the image along with text you want to recognize and that's why you insist on edge detection. I suggest you segment the image and feed text portion directly to tesseract and then apply edge detection. Some pro OCR tools do such segmentation.

Comment: Thanks Tekno.  Which pro OCR tools are you aware of that perform this type of segmentation?  I looked at some of the segmentation algorithms and they seem pretty complex.  I did actually write a segmentation algorithm myself but it did not seem to help much.  It took a lot of work to write the algorithm too and I wound up just going back to an adaptive threshold method which worked better than the segmentation algorithm.